# Composite Key in Spring Data Redis

Tags: spring-data-redis

I have a requirement in which I have create composite key in spring data Redis entity just like we do in spring data jpa using @embededId  and @Embedebble.
I don’t find any equivalent in spring data Redis for this

My entity look like this:

```java
@RedisHash(“User”)
public class User {

    @Id
    public UserKey key ;

    public String fName;

    public String lastName;
}

public class UserKey {

    public String userId;

    public String batchNumber;

}
```

In above I need to declare UserKey custom class as my Redis key which contains two fields

Every time I try to this I get error
Conversion issue from to byte[]

Byte[] conversion issue for UserKey